# How can I suppress the multiple redrawing of Manipulate charts every time, on every evaluation after editing code....?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, evaluation

How can I suppress the multiple redrawing of Manipulate charts every time, on every evaluation after editing code.... After coding a few lines, and evaluating I end up having many many Manipulate charts created below the main chart. This takes a lot of time to delete afterwards.

I am sure there must be  a quick fix - but I search everywhere, documentation, online and cannot find fix..

Many thanks for your help & suggestions. TIA

Comment: if you provide a MWE of the problem you have, someone will show you how. Do not force others to make an example of your problems and also show a solution at same time, then find out later the example they made did not represent what you have. It is waste of time.

Comment: Delete the `Manipulate`’s output prior to editing. Then edit and evaluate.